Access Denied on Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule
I created some rules to forward traffic through Hyper-V firewall into my WSL2 instances. Right now if I create a rule I can remove it, but I don't know why I can't remove this specific rule I created long ago.
Now trying:
Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule -DisplayName "Forward Port 9001 to WSL2"

I get
    Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule : Access is denied.At line:1 char:1
    Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule -DisplayName "Forward Port 9001 to WSL2"
    CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_NetFirewal...ystemName = ""):root/standardci...ewallHyperVRule) [Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule], CimException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 5,Remove-NetFirewallHyperVRule

The rule:
    Name                  : <Redacted> 
    DisplayName           : Forward Port 9001 to WSL2 
    Direction             : Inbound 
    VMCreatorId           : Any 
    Protocol              : TCP 
    LocalAddresses        : Any 
    LocalPorts            : 9001 
    RemoteAddresses       : Any 
    RemotePorts           : Any 
    Action                : Allow 
    Enabled               : True 
    EnforcementStatus     : OK 
    PolicyStoreSourceType : HostFirewallLocal 
    Profiles              : Any 
    PortStatuses          : { 
    SwitchName: <Redacted> 
    PortName: <Redacted> 
    Profile: Public 
    NetworkType: NAT 
    InterfaceGuid: <Redacted> 
    PartitionGuid: <Redacted> 
    VMCreatorId: <Redacted> 
    EnforcementStatus: ProfileDisabled }

Things I tried:

Elevating PowerShell
Trying though elevated psexec
Disabling Windows Defender
Disabling Windows Firewall
Setting Execution Policy to Unrestricted
Adding my user and administrator to Hyper-V Administrators Group
Trying both with mirrored mode WSL2 and without it
Restarting my PC

